# Токенизация строки для разных разделителей

Tags: c++, строки

Как лучше всего разделить строку `std::string` на токены по заданным разделителям? Например для разделителей `{" ", ",", ", "}` и строки `"один два,три, четыре"` функция должна выдавать `std::vector<std::string>` вида `{"один","два","три","четыре"}`.

Обновление: мне казалось, что это видно из примера - разделитель может быть произвольной длины. То есть если разделитель ", ", то разделять надо именно им, а не отдельно "," и/или " ".

Обновление 2: благодаря комментарию AnT понял, что условие всё таки не до конца определено. Если в строке встречается несколько разделителей подряд, причём один из разделителей является подстрокой другого, то деление должно происходить по большему из разделителей. Например, `"один,  два"`(два пробела) должно разделить на `"один"` и `" два"`(один пробел), а не на какую-либо другую пару.

Comment: @VTT разве `std::strtok` отличит ", " от ","?

Comment: @VTT то есть любой разделитель длины больше 1

Comment: `", "` будет таким же разделителем как и `" "` или `","` сами по себе. А если вам нужен токен-разделитель (т.е. когда `" "` или `","` по отдельности не являются разделителями, а вместе являются) - то это другая история

Comment: @VTT обновил вопрос

Comment: Не то есть если у вас один разделитель является подстрокой другого, то надо стараться разделять по более длинному и только потом по более короткому.

Comment: @AnT по сути да. Если будет "один,  два"(с двумя пробелами), то надо разделить как "один" и " два"(с одним), а не "один" и "  два"(два пробела) или "один, " и " два"(оба с 1) и т.п.

Comment: @AnT обновил вопрос

Comment: По прежнему в условии хватает недоговоренностей. А что если на входе "abc...def", а разделители - ".." и ".". В такой ситуации у нас получается "abc[..][.]def". То есть два разделителя, идущие подряд. Что это значит? Есть ли между ними пустая строка или нет?

Comment: @AnT судя по примеру, должно быть "abc" и ".def"

Comment: @brave: Почему у вас в вашем примере `"один,  два"`(два пробела)" второй пробел не считается самостоятельным разделителем, следующим за разделителем `, `?? Как это понимать? Что за логика здесь работает?

Comment: У вас какая-то практическая задача (тогда имеет смысл поговорить о ее хороших решениях) или упражнение на формальную логику?

Answer (score 5):

Для нетривиального набора разделителей (взаимно включают друг друга) лучшим решением будет использование сторонней библиотеки (например, Boost.Tokenizer). Однако попробуем решить вашу задачу с использованием стандартной библиотеки.

---

Проблема заключается в том, что вы используете кириллические символы, а значит для портабельной обработки текста опять-таки требуются сторонние библиотеки. При допущении что в качестве разделителей будут использованы только ASCII символы (как у вас в примере), можно попробовать находить разделители по шаблону с помощью регулярных выражений. В таком случае кодировка остальных символов нас не волнует.

Напишем функцию, которая будет выполнить разделение строки на токены с помощью передаваемого ей регулярного выражения:

```cpp
#include <regex>   
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> regex_split(const std::string& str, const std::regex& reg) {
    const std::sregex_token_iterator beg{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), reg, -1};
    const std::sregex_token_iterator end{};

    return {beg, end};
}
```

Здесь `-1` как раз и означает итерацию по *non-matched* фрагментам. То есть передаваемое регулярное выражение должно искать именно разделители, не затрагивая кириллический текст.

Для тестирования будем использовать следующий код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> regex_split(const std::string& str, const std::regex& reg) {
    const std::sregex_token_iterator beg{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), reg, -1};
    const std::sregex_token_iterator end{};

    return {beg, end};
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto regex_str = R"()"; // сюда будем вставлять текст регулярного выражения
    const std::string str{"один два,три, четыре,  пять  ,шесть ,семь, ,восемь,   девять"}; // строка для тестов

    const std::regex reg{regex_str};
    const auto tokens = regex_split(str, reg);
    
    for (auto&& token : tokens) {
        std::cout << token << '\n';
    }
}
```

В большинстве случаев будет достаточно следующего регулярного выражения (далее текст регулярного выражения нужно вставлять в `R"()"` без кавычек):

```
" *, *| +"
```

То есть `запятая, окружённая произвольным количеством пробелов (0+), ИЛИ 1+ пробел без запятых`.

На тестовом примере получим:

```
один
два
три
четыре
пять
шесть
семь

восемь
девять
```

Что в большинстве случаев и ожидается.

Если же мы считаем отсутствие строки неприемлемым (как между "семь" и "восемь"), то можно убрать "-1" и просто находить всё, что не является разделителем:

```
"[^, ]+"
```

Однако судя по комментариям и правкам к вопросу, вам нужно нечто более сложное. Попробуем для начала такое выражение (далее оставляем "-1"):

```
", | |,"
```

То есть `запятая и пробел ИЛИ пробел ИЛИ запятая`. Возможно, это именно то, что вам надо. Результаты для тестовой строки:

```
один
два
три
четыре

пять


шесть

семь

восемь


девять
```

Как видно, проблема в том, что это не соотносится с вашим примером из "обновления 2". Между "четыре" и "пять" находится лишний пробел и он должен примыкать к пяти, а на данный момент, хоть мы и находим больший разделитель ", ", но также находим и пробел после него как разделитель "пять" и пробела. Нужно как-то указать в регулярном выражении, что в случае пробела после разделителя ", " этот пробел не считается разделителем, а является частью следующего слова.

Сделать это можно с помощью т.н. *negative look-behind*, проверив, что символ перед пробелом не является пробелом, при этом не захватывая этот символ. Если же символ всё же являлся пробелом (как между "четыре" и "пять" в тестовой строке) и захват не произошёл, то будет осуществлён *greedy match*, т.е. будет выбран разделитель ", ", что нам и нужно. Таким образом, регулярное выражение будет иметь вид:

```
", |(?! ) |,"
```

То есть `запятая и пробел ИЛИ пробел, перед которым нет пробела ИЛИ запятая`. Думаю, это именно то, что вам нужно (по крайней мере все условия соблюдаются). Однако есть небольшая проблема: *look-behind* не поддерживается стандартной грамматикой ECMAScript :). А, судя по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539500/6944845), остальные существующие в С++ грамматики также его не поддерживают. Но не беда, ведь *look-ahead* поддерживаются!

Нетрудно видеть, что если мы перевернём строку и в регулярном выражении заменим ", " на " ,", а также *negative look-behind* на *negative look-ahead*, то получим такое же поведение:

```cpp
constexpr auto regex_str = R"( ,| (?! )|,)";
const std::string str{"один два,три, четыре,  пять  ,шесть ,семь, ,восемь,   девять"};

const std::regex reg{regex_str};
const std::string reversed{str.crbegin(), str.crend()};
const auto reversed_tokens = regex_split(reversed, reg);

for (auto it = reversed_tokens.crbegin(); it != reversed_tokens.crend(); ++it) {
    auto&& reversed_token = *it;
    std::cout << std::string{reversed_token.crbegin(), reversed_token.crend()} << '\n';
}
```

Результаты для тестовой строки:

```
один
два
три
четыре
 пять
 
шесть

семь

восемь
  девять
```

Теперь перед "пять" появился пробел, между " пять" и "шесть" один пробел вместо двух. Аналогичная "склейка" и для "девять".

[Окончательный код](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gCspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25OI8SYrEfYJhoAgls7e5iHx%2BfAmKpXN/dm2wy7XgORzcZ1CwC%2Bdwe/yeLzcADdqkRiBD7ncRugQCAEQ4SMD0ZjQUYrvs3h8APoKJK0QgQNAMEb7fEgQngswANkZBDI%2BzpDKZpM%2B7JJmGA80OAHYrHd9jKeQI%2BQQMcyBWSiABrRhkwixJhI/YxcGSs4AOmQBtCEEWnOIptcltIwuADoAtFwTOKACJHKW3WVy%2BkETlKhQq9Wa7XEXUkfaud1WT3e77fP3nAgrBgSiwGh2xhObH3ur2Qu6hQMsJgWsVx5Oy3kED5JYj7JheIiO8lnF4e/YAJXMZgg%2B1I7rc%2BwgRwAYmAwPt5iPSHOzGZE9La/LA0yWdbq0uTB6NCYLNd94fJHuDxYABznw/dm8WM8nizLp8aYcet2Xl%2Bfg9Py8OvdP3Fe94kAkwvzAy8rA/cDfwvRIZXvCdIOQmCILQ0ch0g68n1AtC3TQ79wNHd9PwI%2BD7zcSC3Add8LxfC9jzIkDKOoh1EKfR8KKfIjL1Qz9eKo3c8wLVcZTrINMQFR04xVM5CxXX01wDSTmS5MFhQRYglHQOMTWQYhzQYe1rVNc4GHQS0FPzGtxPXZtW1QTTYh01VUA1eku3bVQKSpGlzi0nSHTeOcbOLJSZX4JsIBbNtCC8gKXMwdA3I8hQzKMqz832eLpyObtEu05LUsYdKDLtUKLEOSxrEIKtJVsv0HKIcw2Va5yipSsMM3y/YACpCEUprZSZNBW1hYFVJZWTMEC4ruoykVK2C2akq69zGDMirCwm459jADZ4jcBgDqG2UFMhT0OEWWhOHiXg/A4LRSFQTghKsSxGWWVZni2HhSAITRrsWNUQDZMxjTZeJ4k2TYNDMS8uCXABOeI2X0ThJAeoGXs4XgFBAN9Aae67SDgWAkA%2BapHLICgYuIYAFGUQwOiEBBUAAd0e/60BYJI6F1DJmbCWg2c5x7nt5/n6DiYAkYCKW6FiAB5Vsxa5zh/qp5BbgZgmOF4bW6nwR7eH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQSdIXQ2gMIwUGsax9DwKICcgRZUCSLp6U4Z10Xy0wassLhxXx761mGRVQmF1n2Y17heC5TB1n%2BjnIySTXSdujh7tICXeFejhsFUam9VUS82WdNlJH2YBkGQfYkeNMwx3er39lwQhoz%2B%2BZM6B%2BZFgQC4sDie1Qc2cVjU2SRJDZNlkfFLhL3FcUNBXjGOCxsuccr/HCYB8ebs4Mxsad0%2BL5JifSECjIQEkIA):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> regex_split(const std::string& str, const std::regex& reg) {
    const std::sregex_token_iterator beg{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), reg, -1};
    const std::sregex_token_iterator end{};

    return {beg, end};
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto regex_str = R"( ,| (?! )|,)";
    const std::string str{"один два,три, четыре,  пять  ,шесть ,семь, ,восемь,   девять"};

    const std::regex reg{regex_str};
    const std::string reversed{str.crbegin(), str.crend()};
    const auto reversed_tokens = regex_split(reversed, reg);

    for (auto it = reversed_tokens.crbegin(); it != reversed_tokens.crend(); ++it) {
        auto&& reversed_token = *it;
        std::cout << std::string{reversed_token.crbegin(), reversed_token.crend()} << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Для решения такой задачи пригодился бы алгоритм одновременного поиска нескольких подстрок в строке, вроде алгоритма Ахо-Корасик.

Если же решать подручными средствами "на коленке", то можно предложить такой вариант. Пусть у нас есть `N` разделителей

1. Отсортировать массив разделителей по убыванию длины
2. Начиная с текущей позиции `C` в строке (изначально `C = 0`), выполнить поиск первой подстроки для каждого разделителя и сформировать массив размера найденных позиций (массив размера `N`)
3. Среди `N` полученных позиций найти минимальную позицию `M`. Если разделителей с такой позицией несколько, то берем самый первый (т.е. самый длинный, согласно упорядочению с шага 1).
4. Подстрока от `С` до `M` уходит на выход
5. Перемещаем текущую позицию `C` в позицию `M` плюс длина использованного разделителя
6. Обновляем содержимое массива, полученного на шаге 2: те позиции, которые оказались меньше `C` обновляем путем поиска соответствующей подстроки с позиции `C`
7. Переходим на шаг 3

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string_view> split(const std::string_view &str, 
                                    std::vector<std::string> delimiters)
{
  std::vector<std::string_view> result;    

  std::sort(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), 
    [](const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) 
      { return lhs.length() > rhs.length(); });

  std::vector<std::string::size_type> nexts(delimiters.size());
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < delimiters.size(); ++i)
    nexts[i] = str.find(delimiters[i]);

  std::string::size_type current = 0;

  do
  {
    auto it_next = std::min_element(nexts.begin(), nexts.end());
    if (*it_next == std::string::npos)
      break;

    if (current < *it_next)
      result.emplace_back(&str[current], *it_next - current);

    current = *it_next + delimiters[it_next - nexts.begin()].length(); 

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < delimiters.size(); ++i)
      if (nexts[i] < current)
        nexts[i] = str.find(delimiters[i], current);

  } while (true);

  if (current < str.length())
    result.emplace_back(&str[current], str.length() - current);

  return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto r = split("abc..def, ghij ief.dkj ,ddd.", { ",", ", ", ".", ".." });
    for (auto &s : r)
      std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << std::endl; 
}
```

Эта реализация пропускает пустые строки, если разделители идут подряд.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s, delim(" ,-");
std::vector<std::string> vs;
while (getline(std::cin, s))
    vs.emplace_back(s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(delim)));
```

После обновления вопроса:
Я напишу на простом примере, а вы по этой логике работайте над любой строкой с любым разделителем:

```
std::string s("one,-         two"), del(",-");
std::vector<std::string> vs;
int k = del.size(),
        pos = s.find(del); // находим позицию разделителья
vs.emplace_back(s.substr(0, pos));  // строка от начала до разделителья
vs.emplace_back(s.substr(pos + k)); // строка от конца разделителья
```

Comment: Так ", " не будет разделять. Я сделал дополнительно пояснение в вопросе

Comment: Это то же самое, что говорить: так не будет заполняться вектор...       А вы попробуйте хотябы.

Comment: Что попробовать?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы разделитель была строкаб а не символ?

Comment: Один разделитель - строка, т.е. может быть более 1 символа. Но всего разделителей может быть много. Т.е. разделители = вектор строк или множество строк или т.п.

Comment: Я обновил ответ на основе ваших комментарий, но  вы старайтесь вопрос задавать на более ясных и очевидных примерах. Если  мой ответ опять вас неудовлетворил, значит я  снова вас не понел...