# Как присвоить переменную пустой строки?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется задачка: вводятся слова, их нужно заключить в квадратные скобки.
Не могу сделать условие для ']', ибо опыта и с алгоритмами  все печально.
Пример:

```
Ввод:
green  parrot
Вывод:
[green]
[]
[parrot]
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string query = "green  parrot";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); ++i) {
        if (query[i] == ' ' || i == 0) {
            cout << '[';
        }
        if (query[i] != ' ') {
            cout << query[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что представляют из себя слова? Какие символы? Что может быть разделителем?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Токенизация строки для разных разделителей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924559/%d0%a2%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: А что это `[]` после `[green]` и почему?

Comment: @MBo там идет два пробела, как я понял, это считается за слова

Comment: @dIm0n к сожалению, нет

Comment: Не забывайте помечать ответы на решённые вопросы галкой слева от них

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам нужно это:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < query.size(); ++i) {       
    cout << '[';
    while (query[i] != ' ' && i < query.size()) {
        cout << query[i++];
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}
```

Конечно можно привести множество примеров решений, но  не интересно, поскольку этих вариантов очень много.