# Как добавить числа из строки в вектор c++

Tags: c++, вектор

Дана строка состоящая из чисел, разделенных пробелом, например: 3, 5, 2, 7, 125. Как можно все эти числа добавить в вектор c++. Проще говоря альтернатива методу .split() в питоне.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924559/312941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Та же идея, что в ответе @Harry, но более коротка запись:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "1 2 3";

    std::istringstream ss(s);
    std::vector<int> vec(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), {});

    for (int x : vec)
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 1 2 3
}
```

Comment: Полезный вариант, но все же тут скорее *создать вектор*, нежели *добавить в вектор* (как это звучало в вопросе)

Comment: А если разделитель не пробел, а например точка?

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, так :)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string s{"3 5 2 7 125"};
    vector<int>v;

    istringstream is(s);
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(is),
         istream_iterator<int>(),
         back_inserter(v));

    for(auto i:v) cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: можешь объяснить как это работает?

Comment: Создается строковый поток `istringstream`. Алгоритму `copy` передаются итераторы на его начало и конец, а в качестве выходного используется итератор вставки в конец вектора...

Comment: А если разделитель не пробел? Например точка.

Comment: Заменить в строке все точки пробелами :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    ifstream fin("task.txt"); //открыли файл
    vector<int> v; 
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        string str;
        getline(fin, str); //считали строку из файла в str
        stringstream ss(str); //создали строковый поток, в который поместили str
        while (getline(ss, str, ' ')) //считываем в переменную str из потока символы разделенные пробелами
        {
            v.push_back(stoi(str)); //Добавляем в вектор число. Stoi(str) - преобразует строку в число.
        }
    }
    for (auto i : v) 
        cout << i << " ";
    return 1;
}
```

Замечание 1: Вместо пробела в while (getline(ss, str, ' ')) можно ставить любой разделитель.

Замечание 2: Если пробелов более 1, в строку попадет не число, будет ошибка.

Замечание 3: Если цифры разделены по пробелам, то можно использовать и copy, как указал Harry. Только copy не принимает других разделителей, кроме пробела.

Comment: А зачем делать `getline` отдельного числа, а потом `stoi`, если можно сразу `>>`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Действительно можно сразу `>>`, так даже лучше.